# IOS Alert not up / Click Alert to go to next page SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I have the code below working where it takes me to the login page once a user Registers their account. What I cant figure out is how to make the Alert box pop up when the account is created, and the user stays on the Register page until they click the "Login" button at the bottom of the Alert box then it redirects them to the login page. Any ideas on how to change my current code below?

```
    // Display alert message with confirmation
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Registration Successful", message: "You may now login. Thank You!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Login", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){ action in
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    alert.addAction(okAction)


}

func displayAlertMessage(userMessage:String) {
    var alert = UIAlertController(title:"Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)

    alert.addAction(okAction)

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: how do you register the user? I guess your server send back a "success" message after the user is created.

Comment: As of right now it just saves the data locally because I have not sent it to a database yet. Just trying to get the formatting done first is all.

Answer (score 1):

So, I assume you want an Alert that says "Registration successful" in the title, has a message that says "You may now login. Thank You!" and it will only have a login button (no cancel button).

I think, what you are missing in your code is a handler for that login action.
Try this:

```
func displayLoginAlert() {

    var alert = UIAlertController(title:"Registration successful", 
                                  message:"You may now login. Thank You!", 
                                  preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    let loginAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Login", 
                                    style:UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        // HERE you perform the segue to your LoginVC, 
        // or do whatever else you wanna do when the user clicked "Login" :)
        // for example: 
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier(theIDOfYourSegueToTheLoginVC, sender:self)
    } 

    alert.addAction(loginAction)

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Attention, this is only the right way to go if your deployment target is iOS 8.0.0 or higher (which I assumed by looking at the question tags. If you wanna go for lower iOS-versions, you have to implement the [UIAlertViewDelegate protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html) and also change your function. I won't elaborate on this now, but if you indeed plan to deploy to an iOS < 8.0.0, and have questions on the implementation of that protocol and the design of the function taking into account different iOSs, feel free to say so in a comment (and to update the tags... :))